# Get unique values in FormArray - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a class that sets up a FormArray of Product Benefits. This array contains `benefitGroupName` and `benefitSettingName` properties.  I would like to loop through this array in my html view to display only unique `benefitGroupName` values, as many of them are duplicates.

```
export class EditProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    productBenefitSettingForm: FormGroup;
    benefitSettings: FormArray;
    benefitSettingList: BenefitSettingModel[] = [];

    AddBenefitSetting() {
        const control = this.productBenefitSettingForm.controls.benefitSettings as FormArray;
        control.push(this.productBenefitSettingFormGroup());

        this.benefitSettingList.push(new BenefitSettingModel());

        this.counter++;
        this.benefitSettingList[this.counter].benefitSettingId = '';
        this.benefitSettingList[this.counter].benefitGroupId = null;
   }
}
```

Model:

```
export class BenefitSettingModel {
  benefitSettingId: string;
  benefitSettingName: string;
  benefitGroupId: number;
  benefitGroupName: string;
}
```

My view is currently spitting out all benefitGroupName values with an `ngFor`
The logic I believe I need to apply is something like  `benefitSettingList.benefitGroupName.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)` to get unique benefitGroupName values but I'm not sure where in my class to do that or how to call it in the view.

```
<div formArrayName="benefitSettings" *ngFor="let benefitSetting of productBenefitSettingForm.get('benefitSettings')['controls']; let i = index; let last = last">
  {{benefitSettingList[i].benefitGroupName}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})

export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any{
        if(value!== undefined && value!== null){
            return [...new Set(value)]; ;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let benefit of this.benefits | unique">
    {{benefit.benefitSettingName}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you show me how I would use the pipe in my current `ngFor` loop?

Comment: <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let benefit of this.benefits | unique">
    {{benefit.benefitGroupName}}
  </li>
</ul>

Answer (score 1):

To simply remove duplicates based on some property once at the beginning

```
const newList: BenefitSettingModel[] = [];
this.benefits.forEach((benefit: BenefitSettingModel) => {
  if (!newList.some(x => x.benefitGroupName === benefit.benefitGroupName)) {
    newList.push(benefit);
  }
});
```

after this you can use this new list to render html elements.

**Update**

Basically you don't need to modify much just before giving it to Angular you filter it for duplicates:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productBenefitSettingForm = this.fb.group({
      benefitSettings: this.fb.array([])
    });

    this.dataService.getBenefits()
      .subscribe((receivedBenefits: BenefitSettingModel[]) => {

        // dump received benefits (possibly with duplicates)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(receivedBenefits, null, 2));

        // filter out duplicates
        const newList: BenefitSettingModel[] = [];
        receivedBenefits.forEach((benefit: BenefitSettingModel) => {
          if (!newList.some(x => x.benefitGroupName === benefit.benefitGroupName)) {
            newList.push(benefit);
          }
        });

        // get reference to the form array
        const fa = this.productBenefitSettingForm.controls["benefitSettings"] as FormArray;

        // fill the form with the list (without any duplicates)
        newList.forEach((b: BenefitSettingModel) => {
          fa.push(this.addBenefitSetting(b.benefitSettingId, b.benefitGroupId));
        });
      });
  }
```

in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="productBenefitSettingForm">
    <div formArrayName="benefitSettings">
        <div *ngFor="let optionGroup of productBenefitSettingForm.controls['benefitSettings'].controls;  let i=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <input type="text" formControlName="benefitSettingId">
                <input type="text" formControlName="benefitGroupId">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Check this working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4w4vc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit-products%2Fedit-products.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how I would use this new list in my html? How would I modify my `ngFor`?